# ClassCastException with Custom ActionProvider

Tags: android, android-actionbar, classcastexception

when creating a menu with an action provider I get a `ClassCastException` error saying the class cannot be cast to `View`. I used the small tutorial on `ActionProviders` in the [DevGuide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) so I am not sure what is wrong.

```
public class CustomActionView extends ActionProvider{

private final Context mContext;


public CustomActionView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateActionView() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_layout,null);
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext,com.app.notifyme.SmsPrefs.class);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }

    });
    return view;
} 

@Override
public boolean onPerformDefaultAction() {
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext,com.app.notifyme.SmsPrefs.class);
    mContext.startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
}
```

Menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/prefs"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/android"
    android:actionViewClass="com.app.notifyme.ICS.CustomActionView"/>

<item android:id="@+id/add"
    android:title="SMS/MMS"
    android:icon="@drawable/android"
    android:actionViewClass="com.app.notifyme.ICS.ContactActionView"/>

</menu>
```

logcat error:

```
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.app.notifyme.ICS.CustomActionView cannot be cast to android.view.View
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:415)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:436)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:173)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:95)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at com.app.notifyme.SmsMain.onCreateOptionsMenu(SmsMain.java:68)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2444)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:388)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:739)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2811)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-21 18:28:58.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17607):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Imports are not pasted in the code, but if you are using ActionBarSherlock (ABS) for ActionBar, you have to to import com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionProvider instead of the standard import android.view.ActionProvider;